# Strange problem with reference and object cloning

Tags: c#, wpf, object, reference, cloning

I have a strange problem with reference and object cloning, which I'm not able to solve.
I have a class MyClass which consist of property Name. I also have my custon user control, which have a property of type MyClass - myclassproperty. These controls are placed on form. If I click one of control a new form apperas. I pass one argument to new form - myclassproperty

```
NewForm form = new NewForm(myusercontrol.myclassproperty)
this.myclassproperty = myclassproperty;
clonedproperty = ObjectCloner.Clone(myclassproperty);
```

clonedproperty is an cloned object. For cloning I use this code, which I found here on stackoverflow

```
   public static class ObjectCloner
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Reference Article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx
        /// 
        /// Provides a method for performing a deep copy of an object.
        /// Binary Serialization is used to perform the copy.
        /// </summary>


            /// <summary>
            /// Perform a deep Copy of the object.
            /// </summary>
            /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
            /// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
            /// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
            public static T Clone<T>(T source)
            {
                if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
                }

                // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
                if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
                {
                    return default(T);
                }

                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                using (stream)
                {
                    formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
                }
            }
        }    

}
```

In new form I have a textbox which is bind to filed Name in object clonedproperty

txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", clonedproperty, "Name");

I also have two buttons on my form ''save'' and ''cancel''. If I click cancel, form simply is closed but if I click save I do sth like that

```
this.myclassproperty = clonedproperty
```

and the form is closed.

In my opinion, at this moment myusercontrol.myclassproperty is reference to clonedproperty so if I click once again on myusercontrol the new value (which I entered previously) shows.

However I have old value all the time :(

Comment: The code is a bit hard to follow without the surrounding context.  Is the first 3-line code snippet supposed to be executing within the form that contains your user controls?  What's up with `this.myclassproperty = myclassproperty;`?  Do you have a local variable named `myclassproperty`, or was this supposed to be `myusercontrol.myclassproperty`?  What are you doing with the `clonedproperty` variable after you assign it?  At the end, you mention executing `this.myclassproperty = clonedproperty` when a button is clicked, so is `clonedproperty` actually a class-level variable?

Answer (score 0):

Without anything else to go on, I would say the form might be using the object and making the changes, and then getting cloned. Try cloning first then opening the form like this.

clonedproperty = ObjectCloner.Clone(myclassproperty);
NewForm form = new NewForm(myusercontrol.myclassproperty) 
this.myclassproperty = myclassproperty;

If this doesn't work can you post the calling forms code?